# How to clean a static return array of char*?

Tags: c

I want to clean this static array of `char*` after using it . I want to read from file and split the lines gotten through fgets()  into array of words return it and clean the buffer (`static char *words`). But this is my implementation of split() and i was wondering if the static char* words will not lead to memory leakage since i can't destroy it because i want to call it every time i am getting a line from a file :

```c
#define MAX_LENGTH 10000

char** split(char* string)
{
  static char* words[MAX_LENGTH / 2];
  static int   index     = 0;
  const char*  delimiter = " ";

  char* ptr = strtok(string, delimiter);

  while (ptr != NULL) 
  {
    words[index] = ptr;
    ptr          = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    ++index;
  }

  index = 0;
  return words;
}

int main()
{
  char   line[]   = "yes you are good ";
  char **splitted = split(line);

  printf("%s\n", splitted[2]);
}
```

Please any idea?

Comment: The nature of the beast of static storage in functions. You could do something like trigger alternate behavior based on a known input value (i.e. the caller sending a `NULL` as `string` resets `index` and wipes the array). But that's a hideous hack that covers the real problem; this is a terrible place to use a static array in the first place.

Comment: Why would you make `index` static?

Comment: Thank i did not notice that index should not static . Thank for the update

Comment: @WhozCraig , I kind of have a vague understanding   of  your explanation .Can you please cite a kind of example or something?

Answer (score 1):

You could reset it at the beginning of the function before reusing it. Basically you are clearing the previous entries in current call.

```
char* *split(char *string){
        static char *words[MAX_LENGTH / 2];
        static int index = 0;

        //reset
        for (int i=0; i < sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); i++) {
            words[i] = NULL;
        }

        const char *delimiter=" ";
        char *ptr = strtok(string,delimiter);
        while (ptr!=NULL)
        {
                words[index]= ptr;
                ptr=strtok(NULL,delimiter);
                ++index;
        }
        index=0;
        return words;
}
```